# Why hair particles not showing the result

Tags: particles

Im making a grass compound wall. I have a plane and given green color and added the hair particles default settings.
[image]

**Default hair particle**
[image]

Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to render the hair particles showing rectangular shapes and not hairs. I want to have grass effect.

**Hair showing rectangular shapes**
[image]
Any suggestion or help why the hair particles showing the rectangular shapes other than hair particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the very bottom of the Particle Settings you will see a section called *Cycles Hair Settings*. Change the 3 options:

- Root
- Tip
- Scaling

These should make your hair thinner to your choice.

Settings section:

[image]

Comment: i have attach the file it has same settings as shown above yet to its having triangular shape

Comment: Use the root setting, and note that they will always stay triangular. Just the base width can be changed.

Comment: I have scale down the root to 0.1 and it work. Thanks

Comment: No Problems, glad I could help