# hair isn't showing up in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I was trying to make a carpet but hair isn't showing up in in renders...why?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78060/why-hair-particles-not-showing-the-result

Comment: Thank you but in my case I don't see the hair in the render...I've apploaded a photo of the render

Comment: You can send the file using this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try checking either strand render or adaptive render?  That could be it.  It could also be that you don't actually have any geometry to the hair, just lines, and that you need to add a: curve - circle into the mesh, then use that as the object for the hair.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve your problem.

You have to play with Cycles Hair Settings > Thickness.

Experiment to copy my values showed in the image below.

[image]